# How to filter the array to another array in angular

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
const arr1 = [
  {
    id: "c1",
    section: {
      name: "emerald",
      room: { id: "r1", name: "Room 1" }
    }
  },
  {
    id: "c2",
    section: {
      name: "diamond",
      room: { id: "r2", name: "Room 2" }
    }
  },
  {
    id: "c3",
    section: {
      name: "gem",
      room: { id: "r3", name: "Room 4" }
    }
  },
  {
    id: "c4",
    section: {
      name: "pearl",
      room: { id: "r5", name: "Room 5" }
    }
  }
];

const arr2 = [
  {
    name: "diamond",
    room: { id: "r2", name: "Room 2" }
  },
  {
    name: "gem",
    room: { id: "r3", name: "Room 4" }
  }
];
```

the expected output should be:

```
[{
        id: "c2",
        section:{
            name: 'diamond',
            room: {id: "r2", name: "Room 2"}
        }
    },{
        id: "c3",
        section:{
            name: 'gem',
            room: {id: "r3", name: "Room 4"}
        }
    }];
```

How do I filter the array to another array. I used the filter but it doesn't work.

here's the code that I tried.

```
arr1.filter((x: any) => [arr2.room.id].includes(x.section.room.id))
```

but it doesn't work. What I'm trying to do is to filter the two array which it will filter the arr1 to arr2. when the data from arr1 not exists on the arr2 it will remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what you are looking for:

```
const arr3 = arr1.filter((x) => arr2.findIndex(y => y.room.id === x.section.room.id) !== -1);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9s52Ln36/

You should iterate over the second array in order to do that.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arr1 = [{
    id: "c1",
    section: {
      name: "emerald",
      room: {
        id: "r1",
        name: "Room 1"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    id: "c2",
    section: {
      name: "diamond",
      room: {
        id: "r2",
        name: "Room 2"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    id: "c3",
    section: {
      name: "gem",
      room: {
        id: "r3",
        name: "Room 4"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    id: "c4",
    section: {
      name: "pearl",
      room: {
        id: "r5",
        name: "Room 5"
      }
    }
  }
];

const arr2 = [{
    name: "diamond",
    room: {
      id: "r2",
      name: "Room 2"
    }
  },
  {
    name: "gem",
    room: {
      id: "r3",
      name: "Room 4"
    }
  }
];

let namesArray = arr2.map(function(item) {
  return item.name;
})

const result = arr1.filter(function(elem) {
  return namesArray.includes(elem.section.name);
});

console.log(result);
```